# CSS trouble getting hover state to behave on simple div

Tags: html, css, hover, rollover

Here’s a tricky one…

I have a div, the contents of which should change on hove over on any part of it.

Here’s a pic detailing both wanted states:
[image: active state hover state]

And here is best effort, so far:
[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CiclB)
..it needs a bit of work.

Any help much appreciated!

Here's the HTML so far:

```
    <div class="item green">


     <a href="#">
      <h4>Welcome</h4>

      <p>Click here to find out more</p>
      <img src="http://www.veropixel.com/res01-170w115h.jpg"/>
    </a>
</div> <!-- /item -->
```

Comment: Have you linked the CSS file which was at the very page you entered here as a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there's my solution http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mIrvA :

```
  $resinGreen: #00a14a;

  .green { background: $resinGreen; }

  .item {
        width: 300px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;

        a {
              display: block;
              height: 98px;
              overflow: hidden; /* cancels img float */
              text-decoration: none;

        h4, p {
              height: 98px;
              line-height: 98px; /* Two lines added to center 
              vertically text of course you can use display:inline-block
               with vertical-align:middle */
              padding-left: 15px;
              margin:0;
        }

        img {
              float: right;
              height: 98px;
        }

        p {
              display: none;
        }

        &:hover {
             h4, img { display: none; }
             p { display: block; }
        }
      }

    }
```

Your problem was that your link haven't a height so it's why it was blinking, i also moved img to the first place for floating

Comment: Thank you so much AlexDom you absolutely nailed it!That's a really clean css solution.

Comment: thank's look at scss in comment i've removed some lines like margin:0 for h4 and p i grouped they together and width from h4 :) enjoy

Answer (score 0):

If using just images within the div this bit of jquery will do it:

```
$('#applyimg').hover(function(){
        $(this).attr('src','/design/sendcv_over.png');
        },function(){
             $(this).attr('src','/design/sendcv.png'); 
        });
```

HTML

```
<img id='applyimg' src='/design/sendcv.png'>
```

Mouseover the image will swop it's source

Comment: Thanks, but I need it to be accessible and text based with html & css, rather than images.